# Examples of non-trivial Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras, kazhdan-lusztig

> I'm looking for examples of non-trivial Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials, specifically in the case where the Coxeter system is a Weyl group.

For example, the simplest polynomial with non-trivial $q$-coefficient is $p_{tsut,e}(q) = 1 + q$ in type $A3.$ Where can we find the first non-trivial coefficient of $q^2$, and $q^3...$ etc.

Comment: The non-triviality of the KL polynomials comes from the non-smoothness of the corresponding Schubert varieties, so you're kind of asking when do Schubert varieties have singularities. This is controlled to a large degree by the theory of permutation pattern containment.

Answer (score 7):

Already in the case of finite symmetric groups, one can find any polynomial with non-negative integral coefficients and constant term 1 as KL polynomial for some pair of group elements.     See the paper by Patrick Polo [*here*](http://www.ams.org/journals/ert/1999-003-04/S1088-4165-99-00074-6/S1088-4165-99-00074-6.pdf).    But specific examples take a little more work.    Check the old tables for Weyl groups (and affine Weyl groups) on Mark Goresky's webpage at IAS [*here*](http://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/tables.html).